# Executar função JS quando usuário escolher o Select

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-select

Tenho um select em html, e quero que ele execute uma função quando o usuário escolher qualquer opção. Agradeço a ajuda.

```
                <select id="frmOperadora0" name="frmOperadora">
                    <option value="0">-----</option>
                    <option value="VV">Vivo</option>
                    <option value="CL">Claro</option>
                    <option value="TM">Tim</option>
                    <option value="OI">Oi</option>
                    <option value="NX">Nextel</option>
                    <option value="AL">Algar</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sercomtel</option>
                    <option value="MV">MVNO's </option>
                </select>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener você pode adicionar um evento de "change" para esse elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o parâmetro (evento HTML) **onChange** para chamar a função.

Código HTML:

```
<select id="frmOperadora0" name="frmOperadora" onChange="teste()">
                    <option value="0">-----</option>
                    <option value="VV">Vivo</option>
                    <option value="CL">Claro</option>
                    <option value="TM">Tim</option>
                    <option value="OI">Oi</option>
                    <option value="NX">Nextel</option>
                    <option value="AL">Algar</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sercomtel</option>
                    <option value="MV">MVNO's </option>
</select>
```

Script em Javascript:

```
teste = function() {
  alert('testando');
}
```

Existem outros eventos que você pode utilizar, da uma olhada no site abaixo:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Tenta

```js
function myFunction(){
alert(document.getElementById('frmOperadora0').value);
}
```

```html
<select id="frmOperadora0" name="frmOperadora" onChange="myFunction()">
                <option value="0">-----</option>
                <option value="VV">Vivo</option>
                <option value="CL">Claro</option>
                <option value="TM">Tim</option>
                <option value="OI">Oi</option>
                <option value="NX">Nextel</option>
                <option value="AL">Algar</option>
                <option value="SE">Sercomtel</option>
                <option value="MV">MVNO's </option>
            </select>
```